# Java user class

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

How I can resolve java user class and JDBC user class? The problem is when i run out put is ther is data in sql.For example

```
public User authenctication(String eMail, String password) {

try {

            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb", "root", "root");
            stm = con.createStatement();
            rs = stm.executeQuery("select * from User,Role where user.id=role.id");
            while(rs.next()) {

                user = new User();
                user.setAddress(rs.getString(""));
                user.setCountry(rs.getString(""));
                user.setCreatedBy(rs.getString(""));
                user.setEMail(rs.getString(""));
                user.setId(rs.getInt(""));

            }
        } catch (Exception sqlEx) {
            System.out.println("sqlexecuteException: " + sqlEx.toString());
        }
        return user;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean? What is the JDBC user class?

Comment: Are you having some sort of naming conflict ? If yes , then try giving fully-qualified name of the class.

Comment: @codebuzz yes it is naming conflict. how i can resolve? give me some hints...

Comment: Refer to your Class (like @CodeBuzz mentioned) using it's fully-qualified name for example com.me.package.User .

Comment: @Hasan : refer to the answer .

Comment: The question is not clear. It needs more info as well as more explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The code above seems to be wrong. You are trying to create and initialize the same object

```
user = new User();
```

again and again all over the result set. Instead use an Array List

```
public User authentication(String eMail, String password) {
    try { 
        ArrayList<User> user_set = new ArrayList<User>();
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb", "root", "root");
        stm = con.createStatement();
        rs = stm.executeQuery("select * from User,Role where user.id=role.id");

        while(rs.next()) {
            user = new User();
            user.setAddress(rs.getString(""));
            user.setCountry(rs.getString(""));
            user.setCreatedBy(rs.getString(""));
            user.setEMail(rs.getString(""));
            user.setId(rs.getInt(""));
            user_set.add(user);
        }
    } catch (Exception sqlEx) {
        System.out.println("sqlexecuteException: " + sqlEx.toString());
    }
return user_set;
}
```

Comment: use arrylist thats the solution to ur problem.

Comment: ArrayList is a performance killer in this situation. Using a LinkedList would be much better. Also your code is a bit messy and has one `while (rs.next())` too much.

Comment: U r ryt... but the problem with him seemed to be that he was trying to declare and initialize the same object all through out the resultset!!! Arraylist will also work since its all of the same type!!!

Comment: I think there is more than one problem in his code and the answer of CodeBuzz is the best until now. (It hits the point)

Answer (score 2):

```
user = new User();
```

Everytime you assign a new Object to `user`, you loose the old. A better possibility would be the usage of a LinkedList:

```
List<User> users = new LinkedList<User>();

while (rs.next()) {
    User user = new User();

    user.setAddress(rs.getString(""));
    user.setCountry(rs.getString(""));
    user.setCreatedBy(rs.getString(""));
    user.setEMail(rs.getString(""));
    user.setId(rs.getInt(""));


    users.add(user);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the [Fully-Qualified Name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_name) of a class to avoid [Naming Conflicts.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg264615.aspx)

For Ex :

`com.me.package.User objUser = new com.me.package.User();`

Where User is the class which resides in the package com.me.package

Try to look at more closely to your query ,it seems wrong to me .

Also use Prepared Statement to avoid [Sql Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want only one user to be logged in. For that, your query is wrong.
You should make it like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM User,Role WHERE (user.id=role.id) AND (user.email='" + eMail + "')"
```

This will give you only the user with the email address you passed.

But there is another way to achive your goal without risking a SQL injection. You could leave your program as it is. You only add one simple line in your loop, just before the closing brace:

```
if (user.getEMail().equals(eMail))
    break;
```

This line will make it possible to exit the loop after the right user was found. So you will return the right one.

Comment: Sql injection  prone code block,should use prepared statement instead.