# Java sql user class

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java user class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979003/java-user-class)

Look at my code. What is wrong? The output is "No user found".

```
package it.unitn.ing.guide;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class LoginDao {
    private static Statement stm = null;
    private static ResultSet rs = null;
    private static Connection con = null;
    private static int i;
    private it.unitn.ing.guide.User user;
    private User user_set;

    public User authenctication(String eMail, String password, int i) {
        try {
            ArrayList<User> user_set = new ArrayList<User>();
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb", "root", "root");
            stm = con.createStatement();
            rs = stm.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM User,Role WHERE (user.id=role.id) AND (user.email='" + eMail + "')");

            while (rs.next()) {
                while (rs.next()) {
                    User user = new User();
                    user.setAddress(rs.getString(""));
                    user.setCountry(rs.getString(""));
                    user.setCreatedBy(rs.getString(""));
                    user.setEMail(rs.getString(""));
                    user.setId(rs.getInt(""));
                    user.setIsLocked(rs.getString(""));
                    user.setLastLoginDate(rs.getDate(""));
                    user.setName(rs.getString(""));
                    user.setPassword(rs.getString(""));
                    user.setPasswordFormat(rs.getString(""));
                    user.setPasswordFormat(rs.getString(""));
                    user.setPasswordSalt(rs.getString(""));
                    user.setPhoneNumber(rs.getInt(""));
                    user.setPhoneNumberNull(rs.getBoolean(""));
                    user.setRegistrationDate(rs.getDate(""));

                    user.setRoleId(rs.getInt(""));
                    user.setUserName(rs.getString(""));

                    user_set.add(user);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception sqlEx) {
            System.out.println("sqlexecuteException: " + sqlEx.toString());
        }

        return user_set;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        LoginDao loginDao = new LoginDao();
        User user = loginDao.authenctication("rashed", "rashed", i);
        if (user != null) {
            System.out.println(user.getId());
        } else {
            System.out.println("No user Found");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That code doesn't even compile, also it's suspectible to an [SQL injection attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 2):

Well assuming that your query is correct and there is only 1 user corresponding to the specified email in your table, you are getting a single result returned but you are skipping over it with that double while loop. Remove the outer most while loop and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your authenticate method was supposed to return an ArrayList of Users while in the main you are assigning it to a single User object.
The user_set you are returning from your authenticate method is the private instance variable user_set which is NULL.

Comment: i have a same java user class and jdbc user class naming conflict. so how i resolve?

Comment: Either use the full qualified path (including the package name) like foo.bar.User OR ou have to change one of the class's names

Comment: which class name i have to change?

Comment: You can change your custom java User class or use fully qualified path like my.package.User user = new my.package.User();

Comment: i m working like that way but unfortunately result is same...